# Convert static object to dynamic

Tags: javascript

If I have an object like this:

```
var obj = {};
```

I can't extend it because it hasn't got any prototype.

Is there any way to convert this object to dynamic so that it's possible to extend it and use new keyword. Something like:

```
obj.prototype.property = 'value';

var newobj = new obj;
```

Comment: you can do: `obj.prototype = {property : 'value'};`

Comment: You can very easily extend it, it's an object! `obj.property = 'value'`, it doesn't need a custom prototype for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with static or dynamic.

You can only use the `new` operator on *functions*, not objects.

You cannot turn an object into a function; you need to create it as a function in the first place.

Comment: By saying 'dynamic', I mean ability to extend it. So is it impossible to use prototype with objects mentioned in question?

Comment: @RuntimeException: You're misunderstanding `prototype`.  Prototypes have nothing to do with "extending" objects; they are only used for constructor function.  You can create any property you want on any object.

Answer (score 1):

the only way is the following:

`var obj = function () {};`

because you can only use the `new` keyword with constructor function. That's it!